# Repeating task with handler take more time than interval

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

I get my data from the server and have to update it every x seconds.
I do this using the `Handler`'s `postDelayed` function.

```
private long mInterval = 10000;


  Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            takeServerResponse(); //with vary duration
        }catch (Exception e){
            itsRunning = false;
        } finally {
            if(mHandler!=null)  {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Sometimes it may take more than X seconds to get new data.
What can I do in this situation?

If we need increase interval,how to determine when to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the duration time of your job and postDelayed your handler based on the duration time.

For example:

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//your job
duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
mInterval = mInterval - duration
```

Comment: can i do that in every iterate?I mean is it OK to do this in every iteration?

Comment: yes, it's ok but you should check it that duration is bigger than your interval or not because it's may make an issue if your interval is negative.

Answer (score 1):

your handler used to call the server response after 10 sec.But Its all depend own your internet speed to get the data from server  that's the reason its take long time